# How to build to same folder each time

Tags: visual-studio-2013, tfsbuild

In TFS the Build number format usually looks something like this:

$(BuildDefinitionName)_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)

However, I only want to retain 1 build and I would like it to build to the same folder each time. So I tried changing it to this:

$(BuildDefinitionName)

But the problem is that this only works one time, then gives an error that the build number already exists after that. I would like to build to the same folder so that I can write a script to zip the latest build, move it to another place, and then unzip it and it would just be much easier if I didn't have to deal with writing code to figure out what the most recent folder name is.

Is there a way to accomplish building to a folder name that doesn't change?

Comment: Hi BVemon, any update on this issue? Did my reply helped or gave a right direction?

Answer (score 0):

This is by designed, every completed build should has a unique build number/name. Otherwise you will get the error above.

> **$(Rev:.r)**
>
> Use $(Rev:.rr) to ensure that **every completed build has a unique
>   name.** When a build is completed, if nothing else in the build number
>   has changed, the Rev integer value is incremented by one.

As a workaround: For vNext build, you could use a [copy Files](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-files) task to copy the build output to the same folder during the build pipeline. To make sure you will always only get the latest build, you could add a [powershell script](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/powershell) before the copy task to clean/delete files in that special target folder.

For XAML build you need to customize the build template and add the default **CopyDirectory** activity in build template to copy the build result to the specified drop location. The detailed steps please refer to this blog. Also add a pre-build script to do the clean operation.

Comment: Hmm... can't say I'm familiar with either vNext or XAML builds, unless that's the foundation for the builds I create through the Team Explorer tab in Visual Studio and I just don't realize it?

Comment: @BVernon what's the detail TFS version are you using?  TFS2015 or 2013 or 2017? And did you create the build in web or in VS?

Comment: Oops, didn't think to add a tfs2013 tag after I added the visual-studio-2013 tag but I've added it now. And I created the build from within the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: @BVernon You are using the old XAML build. you may customize the build template and add the default **CopyDirectory** activity in build template to copy the build result to the specified fixed drop location. A sample with detailed steps please refer to the blog in link below: http://blog.ehn.nu/2010/09/tfs-team-build-2010-how-to-place-the-build-output-to-a-fixed-location/